# subdomain to sub folder mapping

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

e.g. my subdomain is abc.example.com

my folder is /htdocs/abcfiles

my requirement is when i accessing the url http://abc.example.com.
it will display the webpage from "abcfiles/" folder.

my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abcfiles/
RewriteRule (.*) /abcfiles/$1 [L]
RewriteBase /abcfiles/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abcfiles/index.php [L]
```

Its working but "/abcfiles/" showing in some links. i.e abc.example.com/abcfiles/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this code in site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# if /abcfiles/ is in URL then remove it
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/abcfiles/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NE,R=301]

# if hostname starts with abc. then route the request to abcfiles/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abcfiles/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) abcfiles/$1 [L]
```

Have this code in `abcfiles/.htaccess`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# route every request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: its working fine. Thanks. But in page source window its showing "abcfiles/" with links

Comment: That might be old browser cache. Test it in a new browser